# upload categorie to woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

hello I am new to programing. I am creating a simple RSS feed plugin for wordpress to upload some products to WooCommerce and need to upload the category to wordpress . In plugin the category is visible but they are not showing like the url link. I need the category to show like checkbox. Can anybody have any idea ?

File number 1

```
 * Init feed with information from DB
private function load()
 {
     if ($this->id) {
         $post = get_post( $this->id );
         if (!$post) {
             $this->id = null;
             return;
         }
         $this->title = $post->post_title;
         $this->id = $post->ID;
         $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
         foreach ($meta as $key=>$item) {
             $newKey = substr($key, 1);
             $this->properties[$newKey] = $item[0];
             if ($newKey == 'post_category') {
                 $this->properties[$newKey] = unserialize($item[0]);
             }
         }
     }
 }
 ..................
 $fields = array( 'post_category');
 ..................
 // Create post
 $post = array('post_category'  => $this->post_category);
```

And the file number 2 have this

```
<div class="postbox">
    <div class="handlediv" title="<?php esc_html_e('Click to toggle', 'rss-autopilot'); ?>"><br></div>
    <h3 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span><?php esc_html_e('Categories', 'rss-autopilot'); ?></span></h3>
    <div class="inside">
        <ul class="rssap-categories-list">
            <?php wp_category_checklist( 0, 0, $feed->post_category, false, null, true ); ?>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can somebody help me please

Comment: still need more refining... elaborate more... it is not clear what you are expecting

Comment: The plugin loads category data only from posts   But I want to load the category of woocommerce   the code for post categori loke like this      
<?php wp_category_checklist( 0, 0, $feed->post_category, false, null, true ); ?>

the RSS upload from another website the data in woocommerce but the category is missing bicos the plugin load the categori only from posts and not from woocommerce

Comment: so as I have under stood you need the list of you website's woocommerce categories right ?

Comment: yes  like checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms ) {

    echo '<ul class="product-cats">';

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            echo '<li class="category">';    

                echo '<h2>';
                    echo '<input name="product_category[]" type="checkbox" value="'. $term->term_id.'"';
                        echo $term->name;
                    echo '</a>';
                echo '</h2>';

            echo '</li>';


    }

    echo '</ul>';

}
```

Comment: thets look good but thets broak my site look i edit the quastiens and add all the data from  the plugin thets load the category  look over

Comment: over i add all the plugin data how lok like  the call category from posts but thets dosent work  to woocommerce   thx a loooot for your help

Comment: pleeesss help me if you can